# Anonimity for users?

Tags: support, feature-request

There are many users who **need** to make a new account to ask questions here in order to separate their personal stuff.
I would like to suggest creators/devs of this site to get one option for **anonymous post** . It would really help many users

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79390/154443

Comment: so should I delete my post? @RoryAlsop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site is part of a network called Stack Exchange. As a single site, there is nothing a moderator can do to implement such a change. This would need to be a network-wide option, and as such should be proposed on Stack Exchange's [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site.

For individuals who want anonymity, one can always create a new account under a different name. Simply log out of your account and create a new one, or just post as a guest.

Please note that for any user with more than one account, the two accounts must remain entirely separate, that is, one account cannot vote on the other, etc. That kind of action would result in a suspension (or worse) of both accounts.

Comment: hmmm... creating a new account takes a while(like 10 minutes or so) but I completely forgot that you can post questions as guest :P